# Display random number frequency in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to display how many times each of the possible random numbers were generated by having a symbol next to the number. But it is putting the symbols on a new line beneath the number like this:

```
Dice rolled:
You rolled 2 and 4

Roll again [y|n]? n

Number Frequency:
1
2
 x
3
4
 x
5
6
```

How could I make it display the symbol on the same line beside the number?

```
import random

diceCount = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
roll='y'

while roll=='y':
    die1=random.randint(1,6)
    die2=random.randint(1,6)
    diceCount[die1] = diceCount[die1] + 1
    diceCount[die2] = diceCount[die2] + 1

    print('Dice rolled:')
    print('You rolled',die1,'and',die2)

    if roll=='y':
        roll=input('\nRoll again [y|n]? ')
        while roll!='y' and roll!='n':
            roll=input("Please enter either 'y' or 'n': ")

if roll=='n':

        print('\nFace Freqeuncy:')
        index=1
        while (index<len(diceCount)):
            print(index)
            for number in range (diceCount[index]):
                print(' x')
            index+=1
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python3, you can use the optional parameter `end` to remove the newline;

```
print(index, end="")
```

I'm assuming that you'll want all the `x` on the same line too, in that case, do the same with the `print(' x', end="");` and add a newline after the loop.

Comment: This won't help the OP. then all non-counted values will be on the same lines as well.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Joachim posted, you can also use [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html):

```
from collections import Counter

rolls = []
roll = 'y'

while roll=='y':
    die1=random.randint(1,6)
    die2=random.randint(1,6)
    rolls.append(die1)
    rolls.append(die2)

    print('Dice rolled:')
    print('You rolled',die1,'and',die2)

    if roll=='y':
        roll=input('\nRoll again [y|n]? ')
        while roll!='y' and roll!='n':
             roll=input("Please enter either 'y' or 'n': ")

counted_rolls = Counter(rolls)

for i range(1,7):
    print("{} {}".format(i,'x'*counted_rolls.get(i,0)))
```

Comment: The way you've written this, don't you need `roll = 'y'` at the start?

Comment: Yes, but that was already in the original code, I just added the bits for the Counter.  Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

I have created a class for rolling dice, where you can customize the amount of dice in each roller and the sides, as well as keep track of rolls.

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

class roller():

    def __init__(self, number_of_dice=2, dice_sides=6):

        self.dice = defaultdict(dict)
        for die in range(number_of_dice):
            self.dice[die]['sides'] = dice_sides
            self.dice[die]['count'] = dict((k,0) for k in range(1, dice_sides+1))

    def roll(self, times=1):
        print ("Rolling the Dice %d time(s):" % times)
        total = 0
        for time in range(times):
            roll_total = 0
            print ("Roll %d" % (time+1))
            for die, stats in self.dice.items():
                result = random.randint(1, stats['sides'])
                roll_total += result
                stats['count'][result] += 1
                print (" Dice %s, sides: %s, result: %s" % (die, stats['sides'], result))
            print ("Roll %d total: %s" % (time+1, roll_total))
            total += roll_total
        print ("Total result: %s" % total)


    def stats(self):
        print ("Roll Statistics:")
        for die, stats in self.dice.items():
            print (" Dice %s, sides: %s" % (die, stats['sides'])) 
            for value, count in stats['count'].items():
                print ("  %s: %s times" % (value, count))
```

Using it:

```
>>> a = roller()
>>> a.roll(4)
Rolling the Dice 4 time(s):
Roll 1
 Dice 0, sides: 6, result: 6
 Dice 1, sides: 6, result: 3
Roll 1 total: 9
Roll 2
 Dice 0, sides: 6, result: 3
 Dice 1, sides: 6, result: 3
Roll 2 total: 6
Roll 3
 Dice 0, sides: 6, result: 1
 Dice 1, sides: 6, result: 6
Roll 3 total: 7
Roll 4
 Dice 0, sides: 6, result: 5
 Dice 1, sides: 6, result: 4
Roll 4 total: 9
Total result: 31
>>> a.stats()
Roll Statistics:
 Dice 0, sides: 6
  1: 1 times
  2: 0 times
  3: 1 times
  4: 0 times
  5: 1 times
  6: 1 times
 Dice 1, sides: 6
  1: 0 times
  2: 0 times
  3: 2 times
  4: 1 times
  5: 0 times
  6: 1 times
```

Answer (score 0):

You must modify your loop to have it output properly. The else clause of a for loop is visited if the loop doesn't exit prematurely.

```
while (index<len(diceCount)):
            print(index,end="") #let the next print appear on same line
            for number in range (diceCount[index]):
                print(' x',end="") #print the correct number of x's on the same line
            print() #we now need to print a newline
            index+=1
```

Examples:

> > > ```
> > > Dice rolled:
> > > You rolled 1 and 5
> > > Roll again [y|n]? n
> > > Face Freqeuncy:
> > > 1 x
> > > 2
> > > 3
> > > 4
> > > 5 x
> > > 6
> > >
> > > Dice rolled:
> > > You rolled 6 and 6
> > > Roll again [y|n]? y
> > > Dice rolled:
> > > You rolled 3 and 4
> > > Roll again [y|n]? n
> > > Face Freqeuncy:
> > > 1
> > > 2
> > > 3 x
> > > 4 x
> > > 5
> > > 6 x x
> > > ```