# printing while loop (1, 10) before nested for loop ("*")

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to write code in **PYTHON** that will record the results of a user playing the dice game 'In-between' and then print the stats of the rolls at the end of the game, so basically what i want to print is something like this

```
Game Summary
============
You played 3 Games:
|--> Games won: 0
|--> Games lost: 3

Dice Roll Stats:
Face Frequency
1
2 *
3
4 **
5 *
6 *
7
8 *
9 *
10 **
Thanks for playing!
```

Where a '*' is printed for ever time that die face is rolled, however i keep on ending up with something like this..

```
Game Summary
============

You played a total of 3 games:
|--> Games won: 1
|--> Games lost: 2

Dice Roll Stats.

Face  Frequency
 1
 2
 ** 3
 4
 5
 * 6
 * 7
 **** 8
 * 9
 10
 Thanks for playing!
```

So what I want to do is line up the '*'s vertically and same with the index value (1, 10), instead of the '*'s always being put infront of the index values.
Here is my code :)

```
die1 = random.randint(1, 10)
dieCount[die1] = dieCount[die1] + 1
die2 = random.randint(1, 10)
dieCount[die2] = dieCount[die2] + 1
die3 = random.randint(1, 10)
dieCount[die3] = dieCount[die3] + 1
dieCount = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
index = 1
while index < len(dieCount):

    print(index)
    for n in range(dieCount[index]):   
        print('*', end='')
    index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can print it this way, the whole line at once:

```
for i, val in enumerate(dieCount[1:], 1):
    print('{} {}'.format(i, '*' * val))
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the first print(index) is automatically adding the newline after.  Try putting it like the way you print out the *'s:

```
    print(index, end='')
```

Comment: I am not looking to have them on the same line, i am trying to have the number from 1-10 listed from top to bottom as so,
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

and then have stars on the right on those numbers to represent how many times that die face was rolled

Comment: Right, but if you have the print(index) there, it will auto-add a new line, then put your stars.  And after printing your stars, you have the print('*', end='') which doesn't create a new line after. So you have it like this...
print(index) \n
print('*',end='') print(index) \n
print('*',end='') print(index) \n
etc

where you may want to try this:
print(index,end='') forloop[print('*', end='')] print() <=creates /n

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while index < len(dieCount):

    print(index,end ="")
    for n in range(dieCount[index]):   
        print('*', end='')
    print()
    index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

check [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16261345/1561176).

Copied here:

I have created a class for rolling dice, where you can customize the amount of dice in each roller and the sides, as well as keep track of rolls.

```
import random
from collections import defaultdict

class roller():

    def __init__(self, number_of_dice=2, dice_sides=6):

        self.dice = defaultdict(dict)
        for die in range(number_of_dice):
            self.dice[die]['sides'] = dice_sides
            self.dice[die]['count'] = dict((k,0) for k in range(1, dice_sides+1))

    def roll(self, times=1):
        print ("Rolling the Dice %d time(s):" % times)
        total = 0
        for time in range(times):
            roll_total = 0
            print ("Roll %d" % (time+1))
            for die, stats in self.dice.items():
                result = random.randint(1, stats['sides'])
                roll_total += result
                stats['count'][result] += 1
                print (" Dice %s, sides: %s, result: %s" % (die, stats['sides'], result))
            print ("Roll %d total: %s" % (time+1, roll_total))
            total += roll_total
        print ("Total result: %s" % total)


    def stats(self):
        print ("Roll Statistics:")
        for die, stats in self.dice.items():
            print (" Dice %s, sides: %s" % (die, stats['sides'])) 
            for value, count in stats['count'].items():
                print ("  %s: %s times" % (value, count))
```

Using it:

```
>>> a = roller()
>>> a.roll(4)
Rolling the Dice 4 time(s):
Roll 1
 Dice 0, sides: 6, result: 6
 Dice 1, sides: 6, result: 3
Roll 1 total: 9
Roll 2
 Dice 0, sides: 6, result: 3
 Dice 1, sides: 6, result: 3
Roll 2 total: 6
Roll 3
 Dice 0, sides: 6, result: 1
 Dice 1, sides: 6, result: 6
Roll 3 total: 7
Roll 4
 Dice 0, sides: 6, result: 5
 Dice 1, sides: 6, result: 4
Roll 4 total: 9
Total result: 31
>>> a.stats()
Roll Statistics:
 Dice 0, sides: 6
  1: 1 times
  2: 0 times
  3: 1 times
  4: 0 times
  5: 1 times
  6: 1 times
 Dice 1, sides: 6
  1: 0 times
  2: 0 times
  3: 2 times
  4: 1 times
  5: 0 times
  6: 1 times
```